# Changing RGB ints after parsing from hex

Tags: java, android

The code:

```
String green = "#99FFCC";
adjustColor(green);

private int adjustColor(String color){
        int colorToAdjust = Color.parseColor(color);

        //Pseudocode
        int red = colorToAdjust.getRed();  //get red value from RGB
        red *= 0.5;                        //halve it
        colorToAdjust.setRed(red);         //set red value

        return colorToAdjust;
    }
```

Given a string hex color, I parse it to an int. How do I change the individual RGB colors? Above is a somewhat pseudo-code of what I'm trying to do: parse hex, get individual color, change it, write it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply extract the amount of Red by calling `red()` function and then create the new color based on the original values of Blue & Green and the halved value of the Red you extracted before.

You can then create the new color by calling the `rgb()` function and passing it the new values of Red, Green & Blue.

Here is the code snippet:

```
String green = "#99FFCC";
adjustColor(green);

private int adjustColor(String color) {
    /* Get RGB Value Of Color */
    int colorToAdjust = Color.parseColor(color);

    /* Get Red Value From RGB */
    int redAmount = Color.red(colorToAdjust);

    /* Return New Color By Halving Red */
    return Color.rgb(0.5 * redAmount, Color.green(colorToAdjust), 
                     Color.blue(colorToAdjust));
}
```

You can have a look at this [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int)) for more information.

Comment: Which `Color` class has the methods you've used?  Neither the Java FX Color class nor the Java AWT Color class has them.

Comment: @DavidWallace The question is tagged as `Android` and I think the `Color` class of `Android` has these functions. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#red(int)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Probably worth adding `import android.graphics.Color;` to your answer, just to be clear.